# Excel - Count of entries below cumulative threshold without helper column

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have the following little table. I'd like a formula that finds the number of values where the cumulative total (of column B) is less than some threshold (tx).

I tried

```
{=MIN((SUM(OFFSET(B1,0,0,A1:A17))>tx)*A1:A17)-1}
```

but OFFSET doesn't seem to be arrayable like that. Obviously, this would be trivial with a helper column, but for certain reasons that is not possible.

So the correct answer here should be 10.

tx = .8

```
A   B
1   0.112106465
2   0.110981698
3   0.091959216
4   0.082163441
5   0.073292066
6   0.072407529
7   0.071646289
8   0.061646797
9   0.06011448
10  0.057566381
11  0.050341978
12  0.048227061
13  0.043207335
14  0.03940462
15  0.012914194
16  0.007603446
17  0.004417003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really looking for a [MIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-735E28B8-829A-413A-BA38-668FCF0520D7); rather it should be [MAX](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333) that follows your condition.

In E7 as a standard (non-array) formula,

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(1:17)/(SUBTOTAL(9, OFFSET(B1, 0, 0, ROW(1:17), 1))<D7), 1)
```

[image: aggregate_max_less_than]

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to pull 1 less than the minimum index where it was surpassed, thus use of the MIN() function.  Can you explain what SUBTOTAL() does that SUM() doesn't?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if I can accurately describe the differences in behavior here. Suffice to say that the [SUBTOTAL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af)  processes ranges in a more individual or locked manner than a [SUM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) function. Use the [Evaluate Formula](https://goo.gl/Vl25be) command on each to see the differences in internal results.

Comment: I think I've figured it out: in short, given a 2-D array (which is the return of the OFFSET() function in this case), SUM() will simply return a scalar, while SUBTOTAL(9,...) will return a 1-D column array of row sums (which is what we want).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the following **array formula**** due to its non-volatility:

`=MATCH(TRUE,MMULT(0+(ROW(B1:B17)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B1:B17))),B1:B17)>=0.8,0)-1`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The most succinct way to do it I've found is

```
=SUM(--(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B1,,,A1:A17))<0.8))
```

entered as an array formula, or, equivalently,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B1,,,A1:A17))<0.8))
```

Comment: Another option is`=MATCH(0.8,SUMIF(A1:A17,"<="&A1:A17,B1:B17))` also non-volatile

Comment: Nice! leveraging the sort order.