# Greedy sum in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem to create formula (not macro, this is easy) implementing "greedy" sum.   "Greedy" sum adds values in a row up to specified limit.  For example:
if limit is 3 and in row I have values 1;1;2 =>  formula should return 2 (1 + 1,  as adding 2 will cross the limit)

Can you help me?

Comment: See [Count of entries below cumulative threshold without helper column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307162/excel-count-of-entries-below-cumulative-threshold-without-helper-column/35307386#35307386).

Comment: @Jeeped Though volatile solutions should be avoided if a non-volatile one exists (and where the latter does not take overly convoluted measures to avoid said volatility, of course).

Comment: @XORLX - Yes, and that link only shows a formula that returns the count. It would still have to be modified to show what the actual pre-threshold total was. INDEX could likely be substituted for the OFFSEt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming values in `A2:C2` and threshold in `A1`, **array formula****:

`=IF(A2>A1,"No Solution",IF(SUM(A2:C2)<=A1,SUM(A2:C2),SUM(A2:INDEX(A2:C2,MATCH(TRUE,MMULT(A2:C2,0+(COLUMN(A2:C2)>=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A2:C2))))>A1,0)-1))))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `INDEX` function to set limits on a range you enter. Suppose you had the numbers

```
1; 1; 5; 2; 1; 1; 1; 1
```

in cells `F1:M1`, then the formula

```
=SUM(INDEX(F1:M1,1,1):INDEX(F1:M1,1,3))
```

would return `(1 + 1 + 5)`; that is, what is in the first cell in the range to one less the 3rd cell in the range.

Comment: the OP did not want the first three of a range, but to sum until a threshold is reached.  so if the threshold was 4 only the first two would be summed.  If the threshold was 8 then the first three, using your example as reference.  But good job not using offset or indirect.